# How to reduce columns to two?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, line

I am trying to use this piece of html/css https://gist.github.com/ezersky/1484d936fd714f83074c for a line divider. However; when I try to get rid of one column and have it just as 2 with a 25%/75% split it glitches out and makes it go below it and the line divider disappears. Also, how would I get the line divider to not be as near the top as it currently is, I want there to be a gap at the top.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Need a working example.

Comment: Post what ever code you have worked on so far, html and css that would help. Thanks :)

Comment: This is essentially what I have http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/grid-columns-divider

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code pen link: http://codepen.io/saa93/pen/BQNBXB

I used the same piece of code you have posted removed one column made it into col-sm-3(25%) and col-sm-9(75%) row. The divider still holds for screensize min : 768 px.

Hope this helps.

Html:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="page-header">
        <h3>Add the (.grid-divider) class to any row to separate grid columns with equal height lines.</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="row grid-divider">
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <div class="col-padding">
        <h3>Column 1</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima expedita incidunt rerum.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
      <div class="col-padding">
        <h3>Column 2</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptate placeat suscipit maxime tenetur officiis asperiores quae molestias fugiat praesentium dolorum.</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
/* Tablet and bigger */
@media ( min-width: 768px ) {
    .grid-divider {
        position: relative;

        padding: 0;
    }
    .grid-divider>[class*='col-'] {
        position: static;
    }
    .grid-divider>[class*='col-']:nth-child(n+2):before {
        content: "";
        border-left: 1px solid #DDD;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        bottom: 0;
    }
    .col-padding {
        padding: 0 15px;
    }
}
```